# Any way to get the c preproccessor to ignore all #include's?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Using pycparser to parse a slew of .c source files, but the parser can't handle many things in the #included libraries, and I really don't need them for my purposes. I don't need to have it compile, just need to generate the AST from the specific .c I'm processing.
The cpp args i'm passing it right now are:

```
cpp_args=["-D__attribute__=","-D__extension__=","-D__builtin_va_list=void*"]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `#ifdef USE_INCLUDES` perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying the `-nostdinc` option to the preprocessor (and make sure you're not passing any `-I` options).  Given this input in `foo.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        return 0;
}
```

Running:

```
cpp -nostdinc foo.c
```

Gives me:

```
# 1 "foo.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "foo.c"




int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 return 0;
}
```

And the following errors:

```
foo.c:1:19: error: no include path in which to search for stdio.h
foo.c:2:20: error: no include path in which to search for stdlib.h
foo.c:3:20: error: no include path in which to search for unistd.h
```

Comment: Would this catch #include <math.h> and the like as well?

Comment: And if the errors are a problem, just use a `-I` option that points to a directory that has a bunch of empty files with the appropriate names.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the #include guards

If you have the traditional wrapper in each header, eg.

```
#ifndef THIS_FILE_H
#define THIS_FILE_H

   // stuff

#endif
```

Then you could simply `#define` all the header guard tags you want to ignore

Comment: Could you explain a little more or give me an example? I'm not quite sure how to apply what you said. I have a lot of .c files that are range widely in how they are written that I need to do this to. Thanks for the help!